# Error when posting header data and x-www-form-urlencoded data

Tags: ios, objective-c

The data is working in Postman app but not working in below code i.e i am getting error which is mentioned at the bottom. I cannot understand where is error in code. Thanks in advance.

Below are the screenshots of Postman data:

Headers:

[image: Headers]

Body:
[image: Body]

Below is the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://apifm.azurewebsites.net/api/Checkout/CheckoutOrders"]];

// Specify that it will be a POST request
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"Bearer VMuEUFkfBSAfMGhCHYVVEpnN7PWj80RdpSBEJ7gPVtaFQ9P6OHDfKepQcEi3dipPAu3rTHQntRRqbktAQur4rIFIEw05DeKwhhAblVBbbWM8Vzx9HGD9Asmv-cRehQbTKnGlvvT7NuYXn1lsSdoRSa4Ut0JvxYZeZRAmygLaylleT9QWrlKCCA1_rM9GJ_KZFzOAG6VwP70jn0UJaHQChPNLB1Ape_KjMlXiqWv0AjyAiGR4QwSOWNVYIv8QdhuhvSoaQFpcipKUvIyG5fmPKyflETswjPTBF5tZhEdP_kBg6xAIPb7pfJqtbxzyvJ7KilAc84PuByWHogwBIvq0vB4x201b9dBwrJfsxKQB0yEJd9AwqtW8iGFuEdHIfkjyCXjsKAIx4szFS6gaOcQDPTsob25TSEiYAMMlbis7Olbv0lTd6-RSB1Q1KFFERIXszCKCdvznpVMdCST1zaQ3ug" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];



NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[postDict setValue:@"39399393" forKey:@"UserPhone"];
[postDict setValue:@"Manohar" forKey:@"firstName"];
[postDict setValue:@"Adhikari" forKey:@"lastName"];
[postDict setValue:@"testman@foodmandu.com" forKey:@"Email"];
[postDict setValue:@"9988989800" forKey:@"Phone1"];
[postDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"Phone2"];
[postDict setValue:@"na" forKey:@"Organization"];
[postDict setValue:@"Naxal, Kathmandu 44600, Nepal" forKey:@"Address1"];
[postDict setValue:@"this is new address" forKey:@"Address2"];
[postDict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"PaymentOption"];
[postDict setValue:@"DELIVERY" forKey:@"DeliveryType"];
[postDict setValue:@"0" forKey:@"OrderId"];
[postDict setValue:@"128" forKey:@"VendorId"];
[postDict setValue:@"3108" forKey:@"ShippingAddressId"];
[postDict setValue:@"0" forKey:@"BillingAddressId"];
[postDict setValue:@"Here goes special instruction of the customer" forKey:@"OrderNote"];
[postDict setValue:@"null" forKey:@"DeliveryDateTime"];
[postDict setValue:@"192.168.0.5" forKey:@"CustomerIp"];
[postDict setValue:@"54" forKey:@"DeliveryCharge"];


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];

// Checking the format
NSString *urlString =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"jsonRequest=%@", urlString];

NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;



[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (!connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"response--%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } else{
        NSLog(@"error--%@",connectionError);
    } 
}];
```

Below is the error i am getting:

> response--{"Message":"An error has
>   occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an
>   object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"
>   at Foodmandu.Models.DAL.DALCheckOut.checkOutOrders(JObject Jobj, Int32
>   UserId)\r\n   at
>   Foodmandu.Areas.API.CheckOutController.CheckOutOrders(JObject
>   Jobj)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I believe content-type needs to be set to `application/json`.

Comment: @floyddd
You tell to server, that data in the "x-www-form-urlencoded" representation. And then you sent data in JSON representation. The server is disappointed and throw the exception. You should sent data in "x-www-form-urlencoded" representation.

Comment: @Mozilla How to do that? I could not find the answer.

Comment: @floyddd See example here

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m
`- (NSString *)URLEncodedStringValueWithEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)stringEncoding;`

Comment: @Mozilla I am not using AFNetworking for this and you are showing me methods of AFNetworking.

Comment: @floyddd I know, but you can use this, how example for your own code.

Comment: @Mozilla I couldn't understand how to use this. Can you explain it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice - take the AFURLRequestSerialization as a dependency, if you don't want use AFNetworking. For to create a request through it. Add only the AFURLRequestSerialization.h/m files in the your project (+ licence file). Or self write serialization code.

```
NSDictionary *postDict = @{
            @"UserPhone" : @"39399393",
            @"firstName" : @"Manohar",
            .... 
    };
AFURLRequestSerialization *serializer = [AFURLRequestSerialization serializer];
NSString *urlString = @"https://YOUR_URL";
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [serializer requestWithMethod:@"POST"                    
                                                   URLString:urlString
                                                  parameters:postDict
                                                       error:error];

if (error) {
  // check error
}

// Your custom http-header values
[request setValue:@"VALUE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"KEY"];

// send request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:....];
```